# How to make javascript prompt box cancel button to do nothing?

Tags: javascript, prompt

How can I make cancel button in javascript prompt box to do nothing like the cancel button on confirmation box instead of sending "null" values?

Or is it possible to remove the cancel button from the prompt box so there is only "ok" button left?

This is what I have tried but it still sends the null to value to my PHP file.

```
 function AskQuestion(data)
{
   var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
   console.log(data);
   if(data.key[0].status == "ok") {
      var reply = prompt(data.key[0].REPLY, "");
      var index = data.key[0].IND;
      if(reply != "" && reply !== null) {
      //do nothing
      }else{
      jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST",
                    url: serviceURL + "message.php",
                    data: 'id='+id+'&arvo='+reply+'&index='+index,
                    cache: false,
                    success: AskQuestion});
                    }
   } else {
     window.location = "page.html"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your test on the return value the wrong way around. As it is you `// do nothing` when the user enters text, and call `ajax` when they don't. Change

```
if(reply != "" && reply !== null) {
    // do nothing
```

to

```
if(reply == null || jQuery.trim(reply).length == 0) {
    // do nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

```
reply = jQuery.trim( prompt(...) || "" );
if( reply ){
  jQuery.ajax(...)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just return to exit the function

Comment: But i want to have a box where user can write something. That is not possible with alert box, right?

Comment: @user1423276, sorry I miss your point. Seems your code already just do nothing for empty input.